# How to get SpringApplication in spring test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I'm trying to test my code which uses `ConfigDataContextRefresher`.
I want to ensure that refresh works as expected. And bean `TestConfig` will be filled correctly after refresh.

But inside `ConfigDataContextRefresher` defined:

```java
private SpringApplication application;
```

I have next code snippet:

```kotlin
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.RefreshAutoConfiguration
import org.springframework.cloud.context.refresh.ConfigDataContextRefresher
import org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh.RefreshScope
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension
import java.io.IOException
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Path
import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [TestConfig::class])
@SpringBootTest
class ConfigObserverTest {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var env: ConfigurableEnvironment

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var context: ConfigurableApplicationContext

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var application: SpringApplication


    private val scope = RefreshScope()

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var testConfig: TestConfig

    private lateinit var tempDir: Path

    private val dirCleaner = FileCleaner()

    @BeforeEach
    fun initialize() {
        env.propertySources.addLast(
            TestPropertySource(emptyMap())
        )

        scope.setApplicationContext(context)
        tempDir = Files.createTempDirectory("test")
        val configPath = tempDir.resolve("test-config.yml")
        Files.write(configPath, listOf("test:", "   x: 10"))

    }

    @AfterEach
    fun tearDown() {
        Files.walkFileTree(tempDir, dirCleaner)
    }

    @Test
    fun `simple test`() {
        val refresh = ConfigDataContextRefresher(context, scope,
            RefreshAutoConfiguration.RefreshProperties())
        refresh.refresh()
        println(testConfig.x)
    }

    class FileCleaner : SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {

        override fun postVisitDirectory(dir: Path?, exc: IOException?): FileVisitResult {
            Files.delete(dir!!)
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE
        }

        override fun visitFile(file: Path?, attrs: BasicFileAttributes?): FileVisitResult {
            Files.delete(file!!)
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE
        }
    }
}

@ConfigurationProperties("test")
@org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope
open class TestConfig {
    var x: Int = 5
}

class TestPropertySource(
    private val internalMap: Map<String, Any?>
) : PropertySource<Map<String, Any?>>("test-source", internalMap) {
    
    override fun getProperty(name: String): Any? {
        return internalMap[name]
    }
}
```

This code will fail due to impossibility to autowire application, but if I comment this lines, I'll get next error:

```
Cannot invoke "org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getEnvironmentPrefix()" because "application" is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getEnvironmentPrefix()" because "application" is null
    at org.springframework.boot.env.SystemEnvironmentPropertySourceEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(SystemEnvironmentPropertySourceEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.refresh.ConfigDataContextRefresher.updateEnvironment(ConfigDataContextRefresher.java:92)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.refresh.ContextRefresher.refreshEnvironment(ContextRefresher.java:101)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.refresh.ContextRefresher.refresh(ContextRefresher.java:94)
```

due to application is null.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `SpringApplication` isn't a Spring Bean it is a helper class. The `ConfigDataContextRefresher` is supposed to be managed by another component not you. If you check the sources you will see that it is initialized after an event, as you aren't using the Spring lifecycle this will fail. You are running Spring Boot Test so you should be able to just inject the `ConfigDataContextRefresher` instead of creating it yourself. Also I don't think you are testing what you think you are testing, you are basically testing the framework and spring cloud not really your own code.

Answer (score -2):

You should try adding `application.setEnvironment(context.environment)` at the start of function simple test

Comment: It won't work, because application is null, You'll get NPE

Comment: Have you tried using context to retrieve the SpringApplication instead?

Comment: yes, and nothing linked with app in context present, see SpringApplication#run(String... args) -- this function initializes context, but context doesn't have a link to